# How to read SMS from arduino Gboard

Tags: arduino, gsm

```
// libraries
#include <GSM.h>

// PIN Number
//#define PINNUMBER ""

// initialize the library instance
GSM gsmAccess; // include a 'true' parameter for debug enabled
GSM_SMS sms;

char remoteNumber[20];  // Holds the emitting number

void setup()
{
  // initialize serial communications
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("SMS Messages Receiver");

  // connection state
  boolean notConnected = true;

  // Start GSM shield
  // If your SIM has PIN, pass it as a parameter of begin() in quotes
  while(notConnected)
  {
    if(gsmAccess.begin()==GSM_READY)
      notConnected = false;
    else
    {
      Serial.println("Not connected");
      delay(1000);
    }
  }

  Serial.println("GSM initialized");
  Serial.println("Waiting for messages");
}

void loop()
{
  char c;

  // If there are any SMSs available()  
  if (sms.available())
  {
    Serial.println("Message received from:");

    // Get remote number
    sms.remoteNumber(remoteNumber, 20);
    Serial.println(remoteNumber);

    // This is just an example of message disposal    
    // Messages starting with # should be discarded
    if(sms.peek()=='#')
    {
      Serial.println("Discarded SMS");
      sms.flush();
    }

    // Read message bytes and print them
    while(c=sms.read())
      Serial.print(c);

    Serial.println("\nEND OF MESSAGE");

    // delete message from modem memory
    sms.flush();
    Serial.println("MESSAGE DELETED");
  }

  delay(1000);

}
```

Error: GSM_SMS does not a name type....
so i don't understand what actually error is......plz give me a proper answer.
exactly, i want to read SMS using arduino Gboard and doing led on or off through mobile.

Comment: Please can you post the exact error message that you got. "GSM_SMS does not a name type" is meaningless.  Maybe your error is " "GSM_SMS" does not name a type" and maybe this link with a similar error could give you a hint: https://github.com/GROUNDLAB/GSM-ARDUINO/issues/2

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the last arduino software **arduino-1.0.4** and check again the code.

Comment: but latest version is arduino 1.5.2 ......so is it help for me arduino 1.0.4.....?

Answer (score 0):

Please try 1.0.4 (http://arduino.cc/en/main/software) , 1.5.2 is beta. If i wrong sorry...